# Отправка запроса и получения в виде массива

Tags: laravel, запрос

Здравствуйте.При отправки формы попадаю на страничку

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

Как это исправить чтобы при нажатии на кнопку submit меня не кинул суда а просто обновлял страничку.

Во вторых и самый важный после отправки данных в форме получаю пустой массив почему?То есть после нажатия кнопку `submit` меня скидывает на страничку которое я описал наверху `The page has expired due to inactivity.` после `backspace` если нажать на `ctrl + u` то наверху страницы можно увидеть вот такой код.

```
Array
(
)
```

> Почему массив пустой?И это исправить подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот мой шаблон **contact.blade.php**

```
@extends ("default.layouts.layout")

@section("content")
<div style="display: flex;">
    <form method="post" action="{{ route ('contact') }}">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" >
        <label for="e-mail">E-mail adress</label>
        <input  name="e-mail" type="text">
        <label for="site">Site</label>
        <input name="site" type="text" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >

        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <button style="background-color:lightslategrey" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<style>
    input {
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
@endsection
```

Вот контроллер **ContactController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller
{




    public function show(Request $request){

        print_r($request->all());

        return view("default.contact",["title"=>"Contacts"]);
    }
}
```

Также маршрут **web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get("/",["as"=>"home","uses"=>"Admin\IndexController@show"]);

Route::get("/about",["uses"=>"Admin\AboutController@show", "as"=>"about"]);

Route::match(["get","post"],"/contact",["uses"=>"Admin\ContactController@show","as"=>"contact"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было просто

**CSRF-защита**

В Laravel легко защитить ваше приложение от CSRF-атаки межсайтовой подделки запросов. Межсайтовая подделка запроса — тип вредоносных атак, при котором неавторизованные команды выполняются от имени авторизованного пользователя.

Laravel автоматически генерирует **CSRF-"токен"** для каждой активной сессии пользователя в приложении. Этот токен используется для проверки того, что запрос в приложение отправляет именно ***авторизованный*** пользователь.

Простыми словами сказать чтобы надо было отправлять данные чтобы laravel знал что я авторизованный пользователь надо было добавить строку

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

после формы и все.

Answer (score 0):

Используя AJAX и возвращай данные в виде JSON кода, потом этот JSON ты сможешь преобразовать в массив)
Но тут как то не логично, ты запрашиваешь массив данных и перезагружаешь страницу?? зачем тебе это? это как то бессмысленно звучит
В общем я думаю тебе необходим AJAX

Comment: Обычно я использую библиотеку Axios

Comment: спасибо я понял обновления я не хочу. просто  получить массив .

Comment: Тогда все верно, пометь мой ответ как "Ответ")

Comment: мне нужен массив и понять где моя ошибка а вашь ответ это не то что я хотель получить .

Comment: Тогда вот вам ошибка:
$request->all() - получает все переменные запроса, а какие у вас в запросе есть переменные...?

Comment: 4 переменных name email site и text.Все они в label

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72757/discussion-between---and-shtikov).